# Using SqlCommand as multidelete statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I want to delete rows from database based on their Id. Let's look at my current code

```
private static SqlCommand GenerateDeleteCommand(SqlConnection connection, string table, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var idList = ids.ToList();
    var command = new SqlCommand($"delete from {table} where Id in ({string.Join(", ", idList)}", connection);
    return command;
}
```

It probably doesn't need any explaination. However, I tried to use placeholders (mostly preferred way)

```
private static SqlCommand GenerateDeleteCommand2(SqlConnection connection, string table, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var idList = ids.ToList();
    var command = new SqlCommand($"delete from {table} where Id in ({string.Join(", ", idList.Select(x => $"@{x}"))})", connection);

    idList.ForEach(x => command.Parameters.Add($"@{x}", SqlDbType.Int));
    idList.ForEach(x => command.Parameters[$"@{x}"].Value = x);

    return command;
}
```

But this just seems stupid to me. Nothing really can go wrong in this scenario with respect to the data type. I am passing strongly typed collection here so the values must be integers and there is no risk of SQL Injection. Of course, passing a table name might be risky but let's assume that we are always passing one of the predefined const strings containing table names.

My question is, do we have any advantage in the second scenario (it costs us some performance loss).

Comment: Not enough to form an answer to your question, but in general, `int` can be susceptible to SQL injection too, if used in contexts where a leading `-` of negative values can be combined with previous characters. Although that can't happen here, don't fall into the trap of thinking that `int` is inherently safe. And I don't think you've considered what will happen when your `ids` is empty.

Comment: @hvd I see your point. Yeah, I this might be susceptible. However, my question is more about a tradeof between variable arguments length and using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server and most other database providers have to generate a query plan for each incoming query. These query plans can be reused, the query plans are matched to the incoming query text. So if you execute a query that uses parameters the query text itself stays the same even when you use different parameters. This allows Sql Server to cache the plan as well as create and maintain statistics on the query execution. If you inject your parameter values into the query string a new plan has to be created each time the query is executed which is much less efficient.

For more details on this issue see [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I doubt deleting by id, which would be indexed, is too concerning from an efficiency perspective. Additionally, I assume the list of ids varies in count, such that the query plan would not be the same each time anyway.

Comment: @Crowcoder - maybe, maybe not. There is not enough info to say. The statement is very generic, maybe there are tables that are deleted on with very high frequency or maybe it happens every once in a while. It could be that in 99% of the cases there is only 1 or 2 ids that are used for a delete, maybe not. The only way to see if it has impact or not is to execute performance monitoring on the database with the 2 types of queries. This, however, is the only performance reason I can think of to use parameters.

Comment: @Igor Isn't a stored procedure a better choice if we do the same operations over and over again? I bet that server's cache is finite and the execution plans would eventually get deleted and the new one will be needed. With stored procedure we don't have such problems I guess.

Comment: Stored procedures need a plan, too. There's no plan difference between procs and T-SQL batches.